# Grouping fuzzy matches within same column in a data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy-comparison

I am trying to group the similar names of companies basis fuzzy matching ( within same column ).
But neither they are grouping correctly nor do I have the same number of rows in the resulting dataset. As a result of one to many match, the number of rows are more than what is there in original data.

Input File sample with more records

[image]

[image: Input File/Column]

- **Code **

```
df.loc[:,'Account Name Copy'] = df['Account Name']

compare = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Account Name'],
                                      df['Account Name Copy']]).to_series()

def metrics(tup):
    return pd.Series([fuzz.ratio(*tup),
                      fuzz.token_sort_ratio(*tup)],
                     ['ratio', 'token'])

compare.apply(metrics)
```

**Current Output**

[image: - Current Output]

**P.S. The number of rows should remain the same in final output as it is in original data with similar company names being grouped.**

**Desired Output**

[image: Desired Output]

Referred to  below topics, but didn't get the desired output

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865890/fuzzy-match-strings-in-one-column-and-create-new-dataframe-using-fuzzywuzzy](https://stackoverflow.com)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71427827/fuzzy-matching-and-grouping](https://stackoverflow.com)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60987641/check-if-there-is-a-similar-string-in-the-same-column](https://stackoverflow.com)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62085777/fuzzy-match-within-the-same-column-python](https://stackoverflow.com)

Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naïve approach with `partial_ratio` that (*may?*) lead to your expected output.

```
from itertools import product
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")

RATIO = 80 # <-- adjust the ratio here

tups = list(product(df["Account Name"].unique(),
                    df["Account Name"].str.split(r"[-\s]").str[0].unique()))

matches = [(pair[1].title(), pair[0]) for pair in tuples_list
           if fuzz.partial_ratio(pair[1].lower(), pair[0].lower()) >= RATIO]
    
out = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(set(matches),
                   names=["Grouped", "Account Name"])).sort_index()
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't seem to produce the desired output as there are many rows where it's grouping even on the basis of first letter, example 
AB China  life insurance, ABC China Fin-tech, ABC China finance etc. are also grouped as "A", I am open to any other platform or tool like alteryx, VBA, Visual studio, if that helps in such cases

Comment: Oops! But as you may know, I made my code based on the given example and in this one I can't find the names you mention in your comment. Anyways, I wish you good luck ;)

Comment: Sorry - but that's a huge data, I have edited the question to include few such records. Please review..